# R: Summarise the number of outliers for multiple variables

Tags: r, statistics, bigdata, data-analysis, outliers

The dataset has 12153 observations (row) and 194 variables (column). All the columns are numeric. I create a testdata here to help illustrate: (https://s3.amazonaws.com/csvpastebin/uploads/7e6ccfa25a9e91b0f5713d050b860fb5/testdata.csv)

For only one variable, I drew multiple boxplots and scatter plot but it was too tedious going through all the variables one by one.

I wish to get a summary table of the variable name, the outlier value and the number of outliers of each variable. The table should be like this:

```
| Variable_Name | Number_of_Outliers | Outlier_Value |
| BMR | 5 | 99998 |
| ENRGYT1 | 3 | 18189.6; 10958.24; 12641.00 |
```

Comment: Are you sure these are outliers? Or are they just more extreme values? How do you define outlier?

Comment: The first step is to identify the outliers, for sure, different kinds of test are valid here for outliers including chi-square test, cook's distance or some outliers packages in R.

Comment: Also please consider to add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and show expected output based on that so that it is easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your data isn't in reproducible form so I've used the `mtcars` dataset in R instead. You can first load the `tidyverse` and `rstatix` packages for chaining commands and filtering for outliers.

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
```

Then you can create an outlier data frame like you specified by following the comments I made in this command:

```
#### Create Outlier Variable ####
mtcars %>% # use the mtcars data in R
  mutate(id = seq(1, 
                  nrow(mtcars),
                  1)) %>% # make identifier for outlier
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% # pivot only the variables you need
  group_by(name) %>%  # group them
  mutate(outlier = is_outlier(value)) %>% # get outliers for each
  filter(outlier == "TRUE") %>% # only select actual outliers
  mutate(outlier_count = n()) # create count column
```

Which should give you what you want:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 5
# Groups:   name [5]
     id name   value outlier outlier_count
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <lgl>           <int>
1     9 qsec   22.9  TRUE                1
2    15 wt      5.25 TRUE                3
3    16 wt      5.42 TRUE                3
4    17 wt      5.34 TRUE                3
5    20 mpg    33.9  TRUE                1
6    31 hp    335    TRUE                1
7    31 carb    8    TRUE                1
```